# Printing key value pairs from JSON file

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to print key value pairs from a json file. The following is the code I'm using.
I get this error:

> Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of
>   START_ARRAY token

I get this error because the json format is array [{}] instead of object {}. I cannot alter the incoming json file.
How do I go about this?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test4 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


        /**
         * Read JSON from a file into a Map
         */
        try {
            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(new File(
                    "result.json"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });

           ;
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + ", value=" + entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() use new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>()